# Using spiral rule in command line argument

Tags: c, pointers, declaration, command-line-arguments, spiral

what is the difference between the below declarations?

```
char *argv[];
```

and

```
char *(argv[]);
```

I think it is same according to spiral rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written, the parentheses make no difference.

The so-called spiral rule falls out of this simple fact of C grammar: postfix operators such as `()` and `[]` have higher precedence than unary operators like `*`, so expressions like `*f()` and `*a[]` are parsed as `*(f())` and `*(a[])`.

So given a relatively complex expression like

```
*(*(*foo)())[N]
```

it parses as

```
     foo            -- foo
   (*foo)           -- is a pointer (parens force grouping)
   (*foo)()         -- to a function
 (*(*foo)())        -- returning a pointer (parens force grouping again)
 (*(*foo)())[N]     -- to an array
*(*(*foo)())[N]     -- of pointer
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are the same. `char *(argv[])` still means an *array* of pointers.

`char (*argv)[]` would be different as it means a *pointer* to an array of `char`'s.

Answer (score 1):

1. `argv[]` is not a type so `(argv[])` can't be a function declaration - it's a precedence operation.
2. Using the spiral rule we first find `[]` (precedence or not) and then `*`, just as we do with `*argv[]`, thus they are equal.